# Populate Materialize autocomplete with json data

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, materialize

I'm building a little website for a project and I've been searching for hours how to populate my autocomplete input using Materialize plugin. I'm not very familiar with json or ajax so I'm really in pain doing it. The original example from the doc comes like this with static data :

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
data: {
  "Apple": null,
  "Microsoft": null,
  "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
},
limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
onAutocomplete: function(val) {
  // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
},
minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
});
```

My wish would be to get dynamic data from my database. 
I'm using this php code to do so:

```
<?php
        $query = $arg;
        echo $query;

        $json_output = array();
        $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT CPnom FROM competence where CPnom LIKE ". $query);

        while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
                     $json_output[] = $donnees[0]. ": null";
                        }

        return json_encode($json_output);
?>
```

I'm assuming that the code is working because it displays ["JAVA":null, "js":null, "C":null] which match my database datas. 
Any idea how to put this json data in this data argument instead of the static names?

```
data: {
  "Apple": null,
  "Microsoft": null,
  "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var data_2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('key_1'));

    $(function() {

      $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: data_2,

    limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {

      // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
    },
    minLength: 2 // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.

      });
    });
```